# Jenkins : Loop over a JSON List inside a shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
{
"TEST_SCRIPTS":["test_1.py","test_2.py"],
"TEST_SCRIPTS1":"test_1.py;test_2.py"
}
```

This json file, I load in my Jenkins pipeline using :

```
    def load_config(){
        def config = readJSON file "./test.json"
        return config
    }
```

Now, I need a loop in shell script which can execute each python files defined in TEST_SCRIPTS & TEST_SCRIPTS1.

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        script{
            config = load_config()
                sh """  
                    conda env create -n test_env_py37 -f conda.yaml
                    conda activate test_env_py37
                    // Below loop is not working. This env is huge, and mendatory for below code to run
                    for test_script in ${config.TEST_SCRIPTS};
                    do
                        python "\$test_script"
                    done
                    
                    for test_script in ${config.TEST_SCRIPTS1};
                    do
                        python "\$test_script"
                    done
                """
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a groovy approach instead of a shell one, and do all the parsing logic using groovy functionality.
Something like:

```groovy
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        script {
            def config = readJSON file "./test.json"
            def testScripts = config.TEST_SCRIPTS.collect { "python \"$it\""}.join("\n")
            def testScripts1 = config.TEST_SCRIPTS1.split(';').collect { "python \"$it\""}.join("\n")
            sh """  
                conda env create -n test_env_py37 -f conda.yaml
                conda activate test_env_py37
                ${testScripts} 
                ${testScripts1} 
            """
        }
    }
}
```